# How can I play all videos in a play list in turn?

Tags: xamarin, video, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I use Xamarin.Forms VideoPlayer. How can I implement playing all videos in a youtube playlist in turn? It would be also good to be able to display the videos' thumbnails as carousel to let the user switch from video to video. 
I tried this:

```
<video:VideoPlayer x:Name="videoPlayer" 
                   Source="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jwcgm5VYV- 
                   U&amp;list=PLyjPaKJQuCEzqQKdA8FsQdsJ77XbjKkBH" />
```

But got an error:

Error: Unsupported video type or invalid file path.

I found plugin.youtube on NuGet, but it doesn't seem to work with .Net Standard.

What would be the right approach?

Thank you.

Comment: `VideoPlayer` does not support to play the video  with video list address automatically. The better way is that you need to get all the video source url such as `http://littlevideo/TestVideo.mp4` from video list address.

Comment: Thank you. Would you like to make this an answer to let me mark it as such?

Comment: Sure， I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`VideoPlayer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/video-player/) does not support to play the video with video list address automatically.
 The better way is that you need to get all the video source url such as `http://littlevideo/TestVideo.mp4` from video list address then pass the video source url to `VideoPlayer` source  property.