# Setting Source of the FormsVideoLibrary.VideoPlayer in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, video-player, xamarin.uwp

This is a follow up question after this question of mine:

[How can I play all videos in a play list in turn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53414173/how-can-i-play-all-videos-in-a-play-list-in-turn)

Now I know how to play an mp3 file, but I need to play a youtube video, so I don't have an mp3 file, but only Uri. And when I try to build VideoSource.FromUri() and assign it to the VideoPlayer.Source, I get a runtime 
message "Unsupported video type or invalid file path". How can I make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/adamfisher/Xamarin.Forms.VideoPlayer/blob/master/GettingStarted.md#streaming-video-from-popular-sites-like-youtube-and-vimeo

Comment: @Jason Thank you! Do I understand correctly that this feature is a part of a player other than the one I use, and I would need to buy this one to use the markup extension?

Comment: I have no idea - I assume this is the same player you're using, but you weren't specific about it.  I was mainly pointing out that playing youtube videos requires a specific url which I'm guessing is not what you're using.

Comment: @Jason Yes, that is right. Actually, I mentioned what player I use in the subject line of my question.

Comment: "FormsVideoLibrary" AFIAK is just some sample code from the docs, not an actual supported piece of software.  If you're using that then you need to do some research on what the underlying formats supported by the platform players are.

Comment: @Jason Yes, you are right again. It seems like that code supports only path to an actual mp4 file. May I ask if you know an out of the box video player for Xamarin.Forms, to complete this subject? 

thanks

Comment: see the first one I linked to - but it will have the same restriction about url, although I think it has some tools to help discover the url

Comment: @Jason Thank you. Would you like to make your previous comment an answer, and I will mark it then.